# Select Tag in HAML not include class while debug

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, select, haml

I have built a form in which for Gender attribute I have taken as Boolean type. now I am trying to apply class to `select` tag. But class is not appear when I check by right click on form and select `Inspect Element with Firebug`.

**My Code:**

```
= f.select(:gender,[['Male', true], ['Female', false]],{:class=>"select1",:style=>"opacity: 0;"})
```

In `Inspect Element with Firebug` code is appear as

```
<select id="admin_gender" name="admin[gender]">
  <option value="true">Male</option>
  <option value="false">Female</option>
</select>
```

**My JS**

```
$(function(){
  $("select.select1, input.checkbox").uniform();
});
```

I had also tried below code but it gives an error

```
= f.select(:gender,{['Male', true], ['Female', false]},{:class=>"select1",:style=>"opacity: 0;"})
```

Where I do mistake please point me.. Thanks in Advance.. :)

Comment: try something like this:
`= select_tag "access", "<option>Read</option><option>Write</option>".html_safe, multiple: true, class: 'form_input'`

Answer (score 0):

```
        <select id="admin_gender" name="admin[gender]">
             <option value="true">Male</option>
             <option value="false">Female</option>
        </select>


    <button id="click"  type="button">click to add class to select options</button> 
    <script>


    $("#click").click(function()
    {
        $("#admin_gender").addClass("test");
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there is not required to add button for class. I want class in Select.